# Substract struct member with struct member?

Tags: c

Why am I not able to do like this:

```
Time calcTime(Time time1, Time time2)
{
    Time calc1;
    Time calc2;

    calc1.hours - calc2.hours; // It won't subtract!

    printf("Result: ", calc1.hours);
}
```

If time1.hours is 10 and time2.hours is 5, the result should be 5. But the result is 10 because the subtraction doesn't work!

Comment: `calc1.hours - calc2.hours` is an expression returning a value, but you haven't assigned the return value to anything, so it is lost. Neither of the operands are actually changed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo and it serves no use beyond this single situation.

Comment: @user2985498 Don't take it personal, everything on SO is about the content of a question or answer, not a person. The comment above is just a result of my *Vote to Close* on this particular question.

Comment: time1 and calc1 are not related in any way!

Comment: the code would not compile (with an abitrary good compiler and -Wall), because the return-statement is missing.

Comment: Evaluating a subtraction, e.g., `10 - 7` doesn't turn `10` into `3`.  The _value_ of the subtraction is `3`, and you need to store that someplace else (e.g., `calc1.hours = calc1.hours - calc2.hours`, but this can be abbreviated as `calc1.hours -= calc2.hours`, as noted in the answers).

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you meant to write:

```
calc1.hours -= calc2.hours
```

What you do in the code simply calculates the difference of the two values but does not assign it to anything. It will have no effect and depending on the compiler options you may get a warning or even an error for that.

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning the difference to any variable.

You need to do this:

```
calc1.hours = calc1.hours - calc2.hours;
printf("Result: ", calc1.hours);
```

or:

```
Time calc;

calc.hours = calc1.hours - calc2.hours;
printf("Result: ", calc.hours);
```

Comment: that would not help, because calc1 is not initialised with time1

Comment: @PeterMiehle yep. Moreover, author make some actions on uninitialized values.

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing `calc.hours`, `calc` doens't even exist. This code did not compile.